# How to use Tkinter with Real Time database updates

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Can someone help me. I am using two database (srcdb, maindb) and I made an sql queries that fetches data from `scrdb` and checks if there is new data inserted. If there's new data it would update the `maindb`.

I'm using this code to make it real-time. (no issue)

```
while True:
  query.UpdateStats()
  query.UpdateCounts()
```

How do I implement the above code in Tkinter for now I inserted the query inside the update function but it calls the function every 1s.

I need to run the queries whenever the loop inside it ended.

```
root = Tk()
root.title('Title')
root.geometry("400x200")

def update():
  dt_str = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y - %I:%M:%S %p")
  dtCurrent_label.config(text=dt_str)
  query.UpdateStats()
  query.UpdateCounts()
  dtCurrent_label.after(1000, update)

dtCurrent_label = Label(root, text="", fg="green", font=("", 11))
dtCurrent_label.pack(pady=(0, 10))

update()
root.mainloop()
```

Also how to run it without the console it does not work with .pyw and I don't know if it would work if I use pyinstaller since I'm using other python files.

Comment: I am assuming that you are you using Windows. Also how much time do the `query.UpdateStats()` and the `query.UpdateCounts()` calls take? If it's a short amount of time, I think something else in your program is wrong. Can you please post your full code?

Comment: Yes I'm using windows. That actually depends whether there is a new data inserted. The main function of the queries was to clarify if the datetime(srcDb) is greater than the datetime of the mainDb, thats how I determine if I needed to update or not.

I can't actually post the queries since its a complicated structure. I have to transform some string values to datetime to make it work. 


PS: I did not create the db and I'm not allowed to modify it.

Comment: Well if I replace the `query.UpdateStats()` and the `query.UpdateCounts()` with `print("Updating")`, it works as it should. When you said that it doesn't work when you run it with `.pyw`, what do you mean? Does it not appear on your screen?

Comment: what do you mean by replacing the queries? Did you replace it on the update function? I did replace .py to .pyw to make it an exe file so I wont need to type in the console to open the tkinter, but it doesn't work and I'm still trying to find alternatives.

Comment: Because I don't know how `query.UpdateStats()` and `query.UpdateCounts()` work, I replaced them with a simple `print` statement for debugging purposes. When I did that, the `print` statement was executed every 1 sec.

Comment: Oh okay. There's no problem on the queries, the problem is that the srcDb can update multiple times in milliseconds and I'm fetching the data base on the `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM srcDb ORDER BY datetime DESC`

Comment: Add a simple `print` statement in the function and check if it is called every second. From the code you posted it should work. I can't find any problems with it. Also please note that I don't know that much about SQL

Comment: I just have trouble updating the mainDb if the srcDb inserted multiple data in a second. But I think I would just make another query that checks if there is multiple data that is greater than the datetime on mainDb. Just need to find a way to run it without typing in a console.

Answer (score -1):

Use multiple-threading to process it:

```
from datetime import datetime
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import Tk, Label

root = Tk()
root.title('Title')
root.geometry("400x200")


def update():
    while True:
        dt_str = datetime.today().strftime("%m/%d/%y - %I:%M:%S %p")
        dtCurrent_label.config(text=dt_str)
        query.UpdateStats()
        query.UpdateCounts()


dtCurrent_label = Label(root, text="", fg="green", font=("", 11))
dtCurrent_label.pack(pady=(0, 10))

Thread(target=update).start()
root.mainloop()
```

Or just change `dtCurrent_label.after(1000, update)` to `dtCurrent_label.after(1, update)`

Comment: Don't use threading when using `tkinter`. It might crash `tkinter` without giving you an error. **Never** use `threading` when using `tkinter`

Comment: @TheLizzard It is not recommended to update tkinter widgets inside a thread task because tkinter is not thread-safe.  If the thread task is doing something without updating tkinter widgets, it can co-exist with tkinter.

Comment: @acw1668 In this case it calls `.config` on a `tkinter.Label`. In general it isn't a good idea to use tkinter widgets in threads other than the one where the `tkinter.Tk()` was created.

Comment: @TheLizzard I just want to point out that your statement "*Never* use `threading` when using `tkinter`" is not valid in some situation.